# How to specify output dir name for ios simulator when using xcodebuild cli in combination with a xcworkspace?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I build a xcode (6.3.1) project that uses workspace because I'm using Pods.

When I do:

```
xcodebuild \
    build \
    -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyProject \
    -configuration Debug \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -ARCHS=i386 \
    VALID_ARCHS=i386 \
    SYMROOT="/tmp/build/emulator" \
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR="/tmp/build/sharedpch"
```

It outputs the app to:

```
/tmp/build/emulator/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app
```

Is there a way with the `xcodebuild` command to get it build to

```
/tmp/build/emulator/MyProject.app
```

I have tried to replace `SYMROOT` with

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="/tmp/build/emulator"
```

Now it builds to

```
/tmp/build/emulator/Monsenso.app
```

but that do not work smoothly with CocoaPods frameworks (e.g. Typhoon for DI) ~ build fails with:

```
The following build commands failed:
        GenerateDSYMFile /tmp/build/emulator/Typhoon.framework.dSYM /run/emulator/Typhoon.framework/Typhoon
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you could always just create a symbolic link.

Comment: ok then I go for the `symlink` approach for now